# SQL inner joins

Tags: php, sql, inner-join

I need to display data from another table using inner joins.

```
$pid=intval($_SESSION["Patient_id"]); $query = "SELECT Appointment_id, Doctor_id, Patient_id, Appointment_time, Appointment_date FROM Appointment where Patient_id=$pid";
    SELECT Doctor_ID
    FROM Appointment
    INNER JOIN Doctor
    ON Appointment.Doctor_id=Doctor.Doctor_id
```

Currently I have data displaying from one table but I also need to display data from another table using inner joins. How would I insert the SELECT code created into my current coding?  The doctors details is what i am trying to output in my page using the Doctor ID. I am new to php.

Thank you

Full php code for appointment.php

```
<?php
{
    mysql_connect("localhost" , "" , "") or die (mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db("") or die(mysql_error());


    $pid=intval($_SESSION["Patient_id"]); $query = "SELECT Appointment_id, Doctor_id, Patient_id, Appointment_time, Appointment_date FROM Appointment where Patient_id=$pid";
    SELECT Doctor_id
    FROM Appointment
    INNER JOIN Doctor
    ON Appointment.Doctor_id=Doctor.Doctor_id

    //executes query on the database
    $result = mysql_query ($query) or die ("didn't query");
    //this selects the results as rows

    $num = mysql_num_rows ($result);
    //if there is only 1 result returned than the data is ok 
    if ($num == 1) {}
    {
        $row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
        $_SESSION['Appointment_date'] = $row['Appointment_date'];
        $_SESSION['Appointment_time'] = $row['Appointment_time'];

    }
}
?>  

        <strong>Dates available</strong>            
        <select id="Availability" name="Availability">                      
        <option value="0">--Select date--</option>
        <option value="1"><?php echo $_SESSION['Appointment_date'];?></option>
        </select>

        <br />
        <br />

        <strong>Times available</strong>            
        <select id="Availability" name="Availability">                      
        <option value="0">--Select time--</option>
        <option value="2"><?php echo $_SESSION['Appointment_time'];?></option>>
        </select>
```

Full code from line 57 to 98

Comment: It seems like you have all the info you need right in your question. Where are you getting stuck?

Comment: Its displaying a syntax error. Have i left something out?

Comment: This is the error i get. Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /web/stud//PHP/appointment1.php on line 64

Comment: Line 64 is SELECT Doctor_ID

Comment: Can you show the code on and around that line?

Comment: That select statement is part of your actual php code?

Comment: Just what I was going to mention...there are no quotes around it, so obviously it's not valid code.

Comment: edited the question to display the full code

Comment: ok so i put the quotes and now it displays 'undefined'

Comment: I'm not a php programmer but I noticed that the part throwing the error is essentially plain text inside a php code block.  Is that allowed?

Comment: This is the error is giving me now - Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in /web/stud//PHP/appointment1.php on line 70

Comment: Line 70 is - $result = mysql_query ($query) or die ("didn't query");

Comment: What you have is PHP code with some errant SQL code in the middle that doesn't belong there.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the comments.  Try this (new query syntax...)

```php
<?php
{
mysql_connect("localhost" , "" , "") or die (mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("") or die(mysql_error());


$pid=intval($_SESSION["Patient_id"]); 
$query = "SELECT Apointment.Apointment_id, Apointment.Doctor_id, Apointment.Patient_id, Apointment.Time
          FROM (Doctor INNER JOIN Apointment ON Doctor.Doctor_id = Apointment.Doctor_id) INNER JOIN Patient ON Apointment.Patient_id = Patient.Patient_id
          WHERE Apointment.Patient_id='". $pid . "'";

//executes query on the database
$result = mysql_query ($query) or die ("didn't query");
//this selects the results as rows

$num = mysql_num_rows ($result);
//if there is only 1 result returned than the data is ok 
if ($num == 1) {}
{
$row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
$_SESSION['Appointment_date'] = $row['Appointment_date'];
$_SESSION['Appointment_time'] = $row['Appointment_time'];

}
}
?>
```